# Workaround for piping to an if-statement in powershell?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, pipeline, azure-powershell

I wanted to pipe an object to a PowerShell if-statement, but it doesn't work:

```
for($i = 1; $i -le 70; $i++) {
    Get-AzureRmRedisCache -Name "isi$i" -ResourceGroupName "iaas101" | if ($_.ProvisioningState -eq 'Succeeded') {
    Remove-AzureRmRedisCache $_ -Force
}}
```

"The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program". So what should I do instead?

Comment: Try wrapping the `if` in a script block: `... | { if ($_.ProvisioningState -eq ...) ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do something like this:

```
Get-AzureRmRedisCache -Name "isi$i" -ResourceGroupName "iaas101" | where { $_.ProvisioningState -eq 'Succeeded' } | 
    Remove-AzureRmRedisCache -Force
```

You filter with `Where-Object`.

Alternatively you can do:

```
$cache = Get-AzureRmRedisCache -Name "isi$i" -ResourceGroupName "iaas101"
if ( $cache.ProvisioningState -eq 'Succeeded' ) { do stuff }
```

or this (UGLY):

```
if ( (Get-AzureRmRedisCache -Name "isi$i" -ResourceGroupName "iaas101").ProvisioningState -eq 'Succeeded' ) { do stuff }
```

Comment: where one doesnt make much sense since you always get one object (from the first command) ;) but it works

Comment: yes and in that case the Remove-RmRedisCache gets its input from pipeline, so it doesn't want a $_

Comment: oh yeah, its just a copy paste